# wordpress category is empty when i use array_rand variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I declare below the array variable based on my wordrpess categories ID's  ...

```
$randcatarry = array (13,1337,1338,1339,1340,1341,1342,1343,1344,1345,1346,1347,1348,1349,2,3);
$randcatselect = array_rand($randcatarry,1);
echo "</br>";
echo $randcatselect;
```

when I use the above random value in insert post, using below it is getting empty...

```
$my_post = array(
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => 1,
'post_category' => array($randcatselect),

 );
```

please advice how to add random category.

Comment: How should the value getting empty? And where do you use it to tell that it is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only want one entry, array_rand returns the key, it doesn't return the value.

```
array($randcatarray[$randcatselect])
```

That will resolve it.